# Explanation of call ordering in a cout statement, postfix vs prefix

Tags: c++

I was overloading the postfix and prefix ++ operator and testing them out, when I noticed something unexpected in the actual value output when printing out my test.  As an example, here is an integer test:

```
int i = 0;
cout << "before prefix: " << i << " prefixing.. " << ++i << " after prefix. " << i << endl;
```

In my mind, this should print out `"before prefix: 0 prefixing... 1 after prefix. 1"`

To my dismay, this prints `before prefix: 1 prefixing.. 1 after prefix. 1`
Why is it already 1 at the start of the call?!  Ok,  maybe it parses through the statement before printing and i gets incremented before the printing even begins.

But then I tested the postfix integer incrementing...

```
int i = 0;
cout << "before postfix: " << i << " postfixing.. " << i++ << " after postfix. " << i << endl;

before postfix: 1 postfixing.. 0 after postfix. 1
```

The increment happens everywhere but the middle statement?!  This is quite counter intuitive.  Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [post and pre increment in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902638/post-and-pre-increment-in-c)

Comment: Duplicate of dozens of earlier questions. I just picked the first one that was labeled `c++`.

Answer (score 4):

Reading and incrementing a variable in the same statement (or, technically, between two *sequence points*, in this case, the semicolons) causes [undefined behaviour](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.15) - in other words, the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants.